# Online data repository of research in the cognitive sciences

Tags: data, reproducible-research

Sharing data is an important part of science (e.g., see [APA discussion](http://www.apa.org/research/responsible/data/index.aspx)). It's also often useful to be able to have access to datasets when teaching students how to analyse data in the cognitive sciences.

- What online data repositories for research are available in the cognitive sciences (e.g., psychology, psychiatry, cognitive science, etc.)?

Ideally, it would be good to include:

- a link to the repository
- an overview of the size of the repository
- the disciplinary content of the repository
- whether there are restrictions on access and use

Comment: +1, been looking for an arXiv-like site for cog sci research for a while now.

Comment: @BenCole You mean http://cogprints.org/?

Comment: Doesn't pubmed.gov just list everything?

Answer (score 12):

The [ADNI project](http://www.adni-info.org/) (2004–ongoing) aims at characterizing change in cognitive functions and brain structures with age, with a particular emphasis on Alzheimer's disease and neuroimaging.

From the website,

> The overall goal of this huge project is to define the rate of
>   progress of mild cognitive impairment and Alzheimer's disease, to
>   develop improved methods for clinical trials in this area, and to
>   provide a large database which will improve design of treatment
>   trials. We expect that this project will provide information and
>   methods which will help lead to effective treatments for Alzheimer’s
>   disease, leading to effective prevention.

Data that are collected include: demographics, clinical data, neuroimaging (MRI/PET) data, and a wide range of [cognitive tests](http://www.adni-info.org/Scientists/CognitiveTesting.aspx). (More on [ADCS website](http://adni.loni.ucla.edu/about-data-samples/).)
Details about protocols, available data can be found under [ADNI Scientist's Home](http://www.adni-info.org/Scientists/ADNIScientistsHome.aspx). In particular, data are available on [ADCS](http://adcs.org/). Please note that you must write an application to get the data (as is often the case).

Answer (score 10):

The [PROMIS project](http://www.nihpromis.org/) (funded by NIH) built upon a large scale US epidemiological study to assess patient-reported chronic disease outcomes. Data were collected on general population and multiple disease populations in different centers.

From the website,

> Patient Reported Outcomes Measurement Information System (PROMIS) is a
>   system of highly reliable, precise measures of patient–reported health
>   status for physical, mental, and social well–being. PROMIS tools
>   measure what patients are able to do and how they feel by asking
>   questions. PROMIS’ measures can be used as primary or secondary
>   endpoints in clinical studies of the effectiveness of treatment.

Its penultimate goal is to build a calibrated and cross-cultural item bank to assess patient reported outcomes (in particular, disease-specific quality of life, mental health, social relationships and personality traits), for adults and children. The main domains that are covered are described in the [Domain Framework](http://www.nihpromis.org/measures/domainframework). Data are publicly released, but you have to write a short application to access them.

Answer (score 9):

The Inter-University Consortium for Political and Social Research ([ICPSR](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies)) provides 8000+ data sets. Topics include aging, criminal justice, education, or health.

As an example, here is my favorite, the summary of the "500 Family Study". This study includes questionnaire, cortisol, and experience sampling data:

> The 500 Family Study was designed to obtain in-depth information on middle class, dual-career families living in the United States. To understand the complex dynamics of today's families and the strategies they use to balance the demands of work and family, over 500 families from 8 cities across the United States were studied. To address different issues facing parents with older and younger children, families with adolescents and families with kindergartners were included in the sample. Working mothers and fathers are now splitting their time between their responsibilities to their family, and to their respective occupations. This study of 500 families explores how work affects the lives and well-being of parents and their children.

Answer (score 5):

The **[IQSS Dataverse Network](http://dvn.iq.harvard.edu/dvn/)** looks good.

From the website:

> Access the world's largest collection of social science research data
>   here by searching across or browsing through one of the virtual data
>   archives (called "dataverses") listed below. You may also create a
>   dataverse of your own, backed up in perpetuity by the Henry A. Murray
>   Archive, which may easily be customized to appear as if it is on your
>   web page, but in fact is served by the IQSS Dataverse Network. This
>   means that all the scholarly credit, web visibility, and access
>   control for the data devolve to you, but all the work, preservation
>   guarantees, and software and hardware upgrades and maintenance are
>   taken care of by IQSS.

At time of posting it lists `Dataverses: 390 | Studies: 42,018 | Files: 674,076`

Answer (score 5):

It is not specifically for data from the cognitive sciences but [figshare](http://www.figshare.com) might be worth looking at:

> figshare allows researchers to publish all of their research outputs in seconds in an easily citable, sharable and discoverable manner. All file formats can be published, including videos and datasets that are often demoted to the supplemental materials section in current publishing models. By opening up the peer review process, researchers can easily publish null results, avoiding the file drawer effect and helping to make scientific research more efficient. figshare uses creative commons licensing to allow frictionless sharing of research data whilst allowing users to maintain their ownership.
>
> figshare gives users unlimited public space and 1GB of private storage space for free.

(There is more information at their [FAQ](http://figshare.com/faqs))

As of now (August 24th, 2012) there is only one data set that is filed under psychology (from an article by [Wicherts & Bakker, 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.intell.2012.01.004)) but there are several more in the social sciences. Maybe this interdisciplinary repository will grow some more in the future.

Answer (score 4):

This question asks about [Psychological journal that focuses on publishing interesting psychological datasets](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/psychological-journal-that-focuses-on-publishing-interesting-psychological-datas) journals where you can publish psychological data.
Such journals rely on other organisations to provide repositories for the published datasets.

In particular, the journal *Open Psychological Data* has a [page which lists several data repositories](http://openpsychologydata.metajnl.com/about/editorialPolicies#custom-0) along with an excellent summary of important features of each repository (e.g., location, focus, cost, licences, identifiers, sustainability, and depositing instructions). In case the link goes down, hear is summary of listed repositories:

- [DANS](http://openpsychologydata.metajnl.com/about/editorialPolicies#custom-0)
- [FigShare](http://figshare.com/)
- [FORS](http://www2.unil.ch/fors)
- [gesis](http://www.gesis.org/)
- [Odum Institute](http://www.irss.unc.edu/)
- [Tarki](http://www.tarki.hu/)
- [UCL Discovery](http://eprints.ucl.ac.uk/)
- [UK Data Archive](http://www.data-archive.ac.uk/)