# Online datasets for the disjunction effect and violations of the sure-thing principle

Tags: experimental-psychology, decision-making, rationality, reproducible-research, data

The disjunction effect (or violation of the sure-thing principle) is as follows:

> A dis­junc­tion effect occurs when peo­ple pre­fer x over y when they know that event A obtains, and they also pre­fer x over y when they know that A does not obtain, but they pre­fer y over x when it is unknown whether A obtains or not. ([Shafir & Tversky 1992](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001002859290015T)).

This effect has been studied extensively since 1992. However, the papers I've read did not come with the raw datasets. **I was wondering if there are datasets of this effect available online.** A meta-analysis that synthesizes many experimental results would be a good alternative. Of particular interest would be datasets where the effect was observed in two or more different settings (say once with PD and then with repeated bets, etc) with the same participants.

---

#### Related questions:

[What are popular rationalist responses to Tversky & Shafir?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/251/29)

[Online data repository of research in the cognitive sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16/29)

[Human behaviour in one-shot perfect information games](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/1548/29)

Comment: (a) could you cite one or two of the papers you've read on the topic? (b) have you contacted the authors to see whether they would make the data available to you? (c) why do you need the raw data rather than the summary level results that are reported?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim (a) Shafir&Tversky are already cited, but I'll go through my Mendeley and dig up some more. (b) I prefer easily available data that is public to the readers of my work, and I can't make other's data available. (c) the raw data is needed as test/example data for a refinement of a recent model of decision making.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Getting access to publicly available data is often unreasonably tricky. best of luck.