# How can I find open access journals for cognitive science research?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, publication-process

What **open access** journals that publish research in cognitive science/psychology exist?

Apart from PLOS ONE, are there any other open access journals that publish research in cognitive science/psychology?

**Where should I start looking for them?**

Comment: Welcome to the site mob! Please don't be discouraged, but, I have closed your question for the reasons Steven pointed out. If you would like to discuss this further, please comment here. I can invite you into our chat system if that's helpful also. Please do ask a new question!

Comment: On the contrary, I think that the question is worth keeping open (personally I would like to know the answer). Perhaps some rewording may be beneficial. But even for a large scope one can answer with a list of different journals.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Consider using [the relevant meta post](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/36/21) if you want to start a discussion about this instead.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Excuse me, but this question does not qualifies as "A question that involves lists where you want to learn the items on the list but also what is best?". This question well-defined and just asking for a particular list. So it is a well-defined objective question.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal We're still hashing out if lists are acceptable at all on our site. On some Stack Exchange sites they are allowed within certain parameters, on others they're not/ See the [FAQ#dontask]. Also, **we can re-open this question if it's improved or if the community decides it's acceptable**. So if you feel it's acceptable, please [post on Meta](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/) or ask [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2250/cognitive-sciences)!

Comment: [An example of a list with did manage to stay open](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16/21). Perhaps phrasing it in a similar way might help.

Comment: btw, all Frontiers journals ( http://www.frontiersin.org/ ) are open access

Comment: Ben pointed out in chat the list of open access journals is very extensive. I rolled back Jeff's edit and rephrased the question in such a way so it doesn't result in a list of open access journals, but rather asks how to search for them. As such I feel the question is more constructive this way and that it could be reopened. @mob, if you don't approve of this edit, please let me know.

Comment: @Steven probably for the best, but i still contend that the number of reputable open-access cogsci journals is very small. i would be surprised if more than a tiny fraction of the journals listed on DOAJ (Psychology) have an impact factor > 1.

Comment: @Jeff perhaps you're right there are few "reputable" journals out there, but turning this into a list of *subjectively good* journals fitting a criteria makes it even more subjective and less concrete question than even the initial question.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help reworking this question - appreciate what you've done.
Whats the protocol here for refining a question. What I'd like to ask now is something along the lines of what @Jeff mentioned above - are there any open access cognitive science journals with an impact factor >1 or any websites showing impact factors for open access journals in this area.  Should I start a new question or modify this one somehow?

Comment: @mob Don't modify a question in such a way so it will invalidate answers. So no, don't rewrite this question as you suggested. Additionally Ben Brocka has a point in the previous comment. I advise you to start a discussion about it [on our meta site](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/) or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2250/cognitive-sciences).

Comment: The best place I suggest for searching [open access journals](http://www.arjonline.org) is American Research Journal Online. It offers open access journals on various subjects including science journals and Phsycology Journals.

Answer (score 12):

The [Directory of Open Access Journals](http://www.doaj.org/) is a great place to start when searching for Open Access Journals in any field.

You can browse through journals for the specific subject areas like [Psychology](http://www.doaj.org/doaj?func=subject&cpid=128&uiLanguage=en) or [Neurology](http://www.doaj.org/doaj?func=subject&cpid=32&uiLanguage=en), or you can [search for journals or articles containing certain keywords](http://www.doaj.org/doaj?func=home&uiLanguage=en).

The DOAJ lists articles in multiple languages as well, not just English journals.

Answer (score 3):

Another resource is [Sherpa/Romeo](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) which aims to be a site to help you "find a summary of permissions that are normally given as part of each publisher's copyright transfer agreement".

For example, here's what it says about Journal of Applied Psychology.

> - Author's Pre-print:   author can archive pre-print (ie pre-refereeing)
> - Author's Post-print:      author can archive post-print (ie final draft
>     post-refereeing)
> - Publisher's Version/PDF:      author cannot archive
>     publisher's version/PDF
> - General Conditions:
>
>   - Pre-print on a web-site
>   - Pre-print must be labeled with date and accompanied with statement
>       that paper has not (yet) been published
>   - Copy of authors final
>       peer-reviewed manuscript as accepted for publication
>   - Post-print on
>       author's web-site or employers server only, after acceptance
>   - Publisher
>       copyright and source must be acknowledged
>   - Must link to APA journal
>       home page or article DOI
>   - Article must include the following statement:
>       'This article may not exactly replicate the final version published in
>       the APA journal. It is not the copy of record.'
>   - Publisher version
>       cannot be used
>   - APA will submit NIH author articles to PubMed Central,
>       after author completion of form
>   - Wellcome Trust authors may comply
>       using Paid Option.

That said, I'd always double check the accuracy of the information on the site with the actual journal home page and the actual publishing agreement that you sign.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that hasn't yet been mentioned: if you find a paper you want that's not open access, many researchers nowadays put pdfs of their work on their personal sites. The easy solution is therefore to google the name of each author, starting with the first, plus something like "Publications", or if they have a common name, add "Publications, Psychology" to the search terms. Google scholar seems to often be able to do this and help you hunt down the papers easily as well.

Finally, let's not forget that you can just email the first author and they'll send it back to you.