# What psychophysical research published its data?

Tags: reproducible-research, data, psychophysics

**Can you point to published research in psychophysics that made its original* data available?**

*by 'original' I mean the trial-by-trial responses for each subject, and not some kind of aggregate that is usually reported (such as overall percent correct for each condition, or even each stimulus pair).

I am specifically interested in *discrimination* studies, using *2-alternative-forced-choice design*, but any other psychophysical work is also welcome.

I'm aware of [this great question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16/online-data-repository-of-research-in-the-cognitive-sciences) and went over its answers when looking for data. It seems the published data in those datasets is mostly social science, "soft" psychological data and imaging data, and I found only few psychophysical studies, none of them involving discrimination tasks.

Comment: Andrews & Herzberg's Data (1985) includes a data set with the full trial-by-trial data in a forced choice study but it's a study of product preferences (only one comparison, between two products) so probably not quite what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly what you're after, but the [Newcastle Cognition Lab has a data repository](http://www.newcl.org/?q=node/4). It includes a number of learning curve datasets and other studies that measured response time to various simple cognitive tasks.

Comment: Thanks. Its a nice resource, although really not what I am looking for - they provide only an aggregate of the number of times (or probability) each subject responded in each possible way, in each condition. The main feature I'm looking for is the full sequence of trials and responses.

Comment: Anyhow I am just wondering "does it really matter? I mean, the sequence." Cause If it's independent reponse, you could produce the sequence by random generator.. Do you think it might be somehow dependent on previous response?