# Psychological journal that focuses on publishing interesting psychological datasets

Tags: data, reproducible-research, publication-process

There are a range of data repositories around. There are also journals that permit online attachments. That said, my general experience with such online attachments is that the data sharing is an after thought. It is not optimised for accessibility. The information is often not sufficient to truly understand the data.

I'd like to see a journal that specialises in publishing interesting psychological datasets. Such a journal would ensure that the dataset was well documented. It would have clear, machine-readable meta-data. Scripts for processing raw data might be provided.

**Are there any psychological journals that specialise in publishing psychological datasets?**

Comment: [Behavior Research Methods](http://www.springer.com/psychology/cognitive+psychology/journal/13428) publishes papers about norms and other data sets that may be of interest to a wide range of researchers.

Answer (score 5):

**Scientific Data**:
After asking my question, I did a quick search and found one promising journal that will commence in 2014 called [*Scientific Data*](http://www.nature.com/scientificdata/).

> Scientific Data is a new open-access, online-only publication for
>   descriptions of scientifically valuable datasets. It introduces a new
>   type of content called the Data Descriptor, which will combine
>   traditional narrative content with curated, structured descriptions of
>   research data, including detailed methods and technical analyses
>   supporting data quality. Scientific Data will initially focus on the
>   life, biomedical and environmental science communities, but will be
>   open to content from a wide range of scientific disciplines.
>   Publications will be complementary to both traditional research
>   journals and data repositories, and will be designed to foster data
>   sharing and reuse, and ultimately to accelerate scientific discovery.
>
> Scientific Data will launch in Spring 2014 and be open for submissions
>   in Autumn 2013. Sign up for our e-mail alerts or follow us to stay
>   informed.
>
> Scientific Data will be open to submissions from a broad range of
>   scientific disciplines, ...[including] Behavioural data – psychology
>   or neuroscience studies

[**Archives of Scientific Psychology**](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/arc/): This is a new open access journal from the APA. It requires that raw data be made available in a suitable repository. However, publication of data is not the main purpose of the journal. Also, the journal appears to mandate that data only be available once a a request form has been submitted and approved.

> The authors have made available the data that underlie the analyses presented in the article. The data can be used by others for
>   verification or extension of the study’s results. The data are
>   **available from APA or another approved repository upon agreement
>   regarding usage**. If deposited with APA, next users agree to offer to
>   the researchers who generated the data involvement in any subsequent
>   publications

Answer (score 5):

[The Journal of Open Psychology Data:](http://openpsychologydata.metajnl.com/)

A great project spearheaded by Jelte M. Wicherts, longtime open science advocate.

Unfortunately, it has only published one paper so far.