# Are there peer-reviewed psychology or neuroscience journal articles that include the raw data (data set)?

Tags: reproducible-research

I am hoping to carry out a pedagogical analysis of some peer reviewed papers, preferably on topics in cognitive science.

This would be easier with the raw data its self, in additional to the results section of the paper.

Comment: Research gate offers the possibility of sharing data sets. In general, I think it does not happen often that data is made publicly available. Instead of looking for data, perhaps look for suitable papers and contact the authors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [*Psychological Science*](http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/publications/journals/psychological_science) articles with the ["Open Data Badge"](http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/publications/journals/psychological_science/badges).  There's also the [*Journal of Open Psychology Data*](http://openpsychologydata.metajnl.com).

Comment: Interesting answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

See this [previous question about journals that specialise in publishing psychological datasets](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/psychological-journal-that-focuses-on-publishing-interesting-psychological-datas).

See the [reproducible-research](/questions/tagged/reproducible-research) tag for some more specific examples.

[PlosOne Psychology](http://www.plosone.org/browse/psychology) has recently increased its requirements to supply raw data. So recent psychological research in the journal is more likely to have data attached to the manuscript. I did a quick look and found a small but meaningful proportion had raw data attached.

In general, there are a range of journal policies around the requirement to make raw data available. There is a move towards greater access to raw data. So a good place to look is journals that have a greater requirement for data access. But even then, you typically still have to hunt around.